# Scrapy crawling data from a forum

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to Scrapy.
I want to crawl all post from a forum, and up-to-date for those new post.
There are some questions i want to figure out.

1.How do I ensure that the crawler wont crawl the a post twice??

2.if there is some mechanism that avoid crawling a post twice. Will this mechanism work even i restart the crawler?

3.will the crawler keep crawling the new post automatically??

4.what db / plugin I need to use in this project?

here is the initialize of spider class

```
name = "forum"
    allowed_domains = ["forum.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://s7.forum.com/posts.aspx',
    )

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('mid=', )), callback='parse_item'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to customize a mechanism yourself and put it in settings. Like this:

from scrapy.dupefilter import RFPDupeFilter

class SeenURLFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

```
def __init__(self, path=None):
    self.urls_seen = set()
    RFPDupeFilter.__init__(self, path)

def request_seen(self, request):
    if request.url in self.urls_seen:
        return True
    else:
        self.urls_seen.add(request.url)
```

Be sure to add the DUPEFILTER_CLASS constant to settings.py:

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scraper.custom_filters.SeenURLFilter'
```

2. Yes. It will work as long as crawl is running
3. Yes.
4. I don't see the difficulty here. Use whatever db you are familiar with.

Comment: thanks, but what if I restart the crawler? can the RFPDupeFilter work with a DB to filter duplicated record??

Comment: @SiuChungChan I think you should look for the record in the db to see if it's duplicated. This filter won't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but the make it generic , is it better to only check for the record in db every time?
otherwise i need to check using filter and db as long as I restart the crawler. Or there is still some benefit for using RFPdupeFilter?

Comment: @SiuChungChan I think it depends on your demand and real environment. If there is not much data in your db, you can read all of them to memory and do compare with SeenURLFilter. If there is too much data in your db, you have to check for the record in db every time. I think finding an efficient way to store URL in db and read all of them out for comparing would be the best solution.